# FastAPI testing an endpoint over a large dataset async with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, pytest-asyncio

I have a fairly large dataset that I would like to use for testing a FastAPI endpoint.
The issue I am having is that tests take a really long time to run. I am not sure if I have parameterized my tests correctly or if I have async setup correctly.

```py
# Note: Func names, paths and other information is obfuscated
import pandas as pd
import pytest_asyncio
import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient

from MODULE import app #FastAPI

dataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

@pytest_asyncio.fixture()
async def async_app_client():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url='http://localhost') as client:
        yield client

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@pytest.mark.parametrize("term", dataset['value'])
async def test_on_term(async_app_client, term):
    response = await async_app_client.get(f"/endpoint?text={term}")
    assert response.status_code == 200, f"{term} returned non 200 status"
```

Does this setup look correct? Tests run using this setup but the execution time for all the tests is abnormally long. Any other ideas to speed this up would be appreciated!

I've tried using `pytest-xdist` but due to the nature of the data, sometimes there are repeated values and inconsistencies between results for a given test.

Comment: The variable 'dataset' is not used, do you need to read the csv file?

Comment: Sorry, a typo in my write up. @TomMcLean I've fixed it above.

Comment: Can you post the code of what "/endpoint?text=" is and also a sample of dataset['value']?

Comment: I can't publish the code to the endpoint - but in short it reads in the data, processes it and does a read/write from a db. The endpoint is not specified as `async` within fastapi. An example of a `value` is any string. eg., "red firetruck", "20 foot long hotdog"

Comment: Have you measured how long each iteration of your test takes? For any large enough dataset, it will take time unless you parallelize it across many computers.

Comment: Great point @MatsLindh. I did eventually end up doing this approach. I just had to ensure test cases were entirely unique in data

Answer (score 1):

Even though the tests are async `pytest-asyncio` runs the tests serially (ie. one after another).

You want to check out `pytest-asyncio-cooperative` which runs the tests using cooperative multitasking (ie. the tests will be run concurrently). You will see a speed up because this test suite is I/O bound (which pytest-asyncio-cooperative excels at).

Disclaimer: I am the developer of pytest-asyncio-cooperative